# What is the right choice between canvas and svg for circular daily planner

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, electron

I am a pretty new programmer (wannabe programmer technically) and I would like to ask you guys a question about graphic tools in html5 for my project.
I plan to make a planner app by using electron and the planner form should be round. [this is the planner I am talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YFP8.png) And I want to add event handlers for each circular sector to add new or edit existing lists.
So My question is, Which is the proper method between canvas and svg in this case? What I mean is, which method is easy to implement (or needs shorter codes) and which one has faster rendering speed and better performance?

Comment: SVG, since you can't declare shapes and add event handlers with Canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with SVG if you're a beginner. Rendering will be easier and so will event management. Don't worry too much about performance, they'll both do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Find a higher-level library (d3 springs to mind), that looks like it has functions most suitable for your application, and use whatever (canvas, svg, webgl, ...) it is built on.

Other considerations: if your technology choice doesn't work on a platform you need it to, then don't use it. (Unlikely to be an issue, as your tags suggest this is an Electron app.)